# Open pdf in presentation mode vie command line using Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: windows, command-line, acrobat

I used to open pdfs in an electron application directly in presentation mode using following command

```
start "" /max "C:\\path..to\\AcroRd32.exe" /A "pagemode=fullscreen" "C:\path..to\myFile.pdf"
```

But it seems that those parameters are not working anymore since Readers DC version. Does anyone know if there are still possibilities to open a pdf in presentation mode via command line?

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Pagemode refers to the sidebar the default is none.
commandline parameters for DC https://corpora.tika.apache.org/base/docs/bug_trackers/pdf.js/pdf.js-LINK-2843-0.pdf and older https://pdfobject.com/pdf/pdf_open_parameters_acro8.pdf are effectively still the same set.

**Here is /A "pagemode=thumbs" AND /A "pagemode=bookmarks" when there are none.**
[image][image]

Here is /A "pagemode=bookmarks" when there are at least one
[image]

**Hence using Pagemode=fullscreen is a perpetuated urban myth (much like robot outputs)**

There were several ways in the past to obtain a full screen reader page. So if loaded in past by an Internet Explorer ActiveX Web Application it was perhaps possible (with sidebar pane perhaps default to "none" as fullscreen now would simply be ignored)

> "When PDFs open in a web page, they open in Read mode. Read mode displays the PDF without the menus, panes, or toolbars visible."

However with default Reader MSEdge "Powered by Acrobat" those Trident methods are effectively gone. There may be other options unknown to me, especially as its newer behaviours, but for presentation Kiosk mode is required.

### Answer

A PDF creator can set a PDF to open in Full Screen mode, or you can set the view yourself. Full Screen mode (light background) is often used for presentations (dark background), sometimes with automatic page advancement and transitions.

For Acrobat PDF's Presentation / Fullscreen mode is controlled by documents.

> Acrobat Pro, Action wizards enable changing default settings for multiple documents.

> For Presentations:
> Select Open in Full Screen mode check box.
> For the Navigation tab, select Page Only.
> For Page layout, select Single Page.
> Set Open to page to the page where you want to start the presentation.
> [image]

Other editors are available
[image]

Other readers that do not allow document control such as SumatraPDF will have a command line option for `-fullscreen` and or `-presentation`.

**For Windows** the general purpose file viewer in window or presentation web mode is native MsEdge.exe. Here running in application mode with an ePub as window or started full screen (not presentation). You can use whichever switches work well together.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-first-run --enable-features=msEdgeEpubReaderEnabled --app="path to \filename.pdf"` (or .epub)
```

For full screen (not presentation) you currently need both switches (Chrome PLUS Edge) and with or without either of the two above `--enable-features=msEdgeEpubReaderEnabled --app=`,  however to switch from full screen to presentation you need to click an extra icon, which switches to "PDF fullscreen" (Black presentation background).

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --start-fullscreen "local or remote filepath & name"
```

[image]

Comment: As it is true that "pagemode=fullscreen" might not work any more it is not an urban myth. I used it long enough in my software and it worked perfectly. Sadly I do not have access to the pdf files, so I cannot change them. The task is opening them in Adobe reader in presentation mode without altering the files. Until the DC version this could be done.

Comment: I can absolutely assure you it worked. Regardless of the pdf-file. My software had that implemented for years and I never had any troubles. Maybe it was a never officially supported - I don't know. But it worked.